# Монтировать раздел по SSH и получить права на редактирование

Tags: ssh, права, sshfs

Есть удалённый сервер, на котором периодически нужно править конфиги. Сейчас я захожу через SSH с ключом и правлю через Vim (`sudo vim filename`). Хотел бы использовать что-то более привычное.

Попытался монтировать файловую систему:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/path/to/user.key username@1.2.3.4:/ ~/mounted.fs
```

Монтировал относительно успешно. Могу сделать на своей машине `cat filename`, но не могу `sudo gedit filename`. В Krusader файлы открываются для редактирования (F4), но сохранять не даёт:

> The document could not be saved, as it was not possible to write to ~/mounted.fs/path/to/file.conf
>
> Check that you have write access to this file or that enough disk space is available

Как и где можно добавить себе права на редактирование? Безопасно ли это?

Comment: Из  http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/SshfsFaq/#why-does-svn-etc-fail-with-permission-denied   `Why does SVN (etc...) fail with permission denied?

This is a bug that happens when an application creates a read-only file opened for writing (e.g. open("foo", O_WRONLY||O_CREAT, 0444))

It has been fixed in sshfs version 1.3, but also requires FUSE version >2.5.X and Linux kernel version >2.6.15.`  Не Ваш случай?

Comment: @avp спасибо, нет, не мой. Оказалось всё проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

более безопасно, конечно, открывать *shell* на удалённой машине под именем «рядового» пользователя, и уже там повышать привилегии (с помощью `sudo` или, на худой конец, `su`) для процессов, запущенных на удалённой машине.

---

понятно, что в случае монтирования файловой системы, для процесса, запущенного на локальной машине, такое повышение привилегий сделать невозможно: процесс *sshd*, который «отвечает» за монтирование на «той стороне» запускается и работает от имени пользователя, под которым вы подключились к удалённой машине.

поэтому, гораздо менее безопасно, но «если очень хочется», то (технически) можно сразу подключаться под именем привилегированного пользователя (т.е., root-а).

---

для этого «пропишите» свой публичный ключ в соответствующий файл пользователя *root* на удалённой машине:

1. скопируйте на удалённую машину свой публичный ключ (скорее всего, это будет `id_rsa.pub`):

   ```
   $ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub пользователь@удалённая-машина:/tmp/мой.ключ
   ```
2. затем (на удалённой машине) создайте каталог:

   ```
   у.м.$ sudo mkdir -p /root/.ssh
   ```
3. добавьте (там же) скопированный ключ в файл `authorized_keys`:

   ```
   у.м.$ cat /tmp/мой.ключ | sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
4. и измените принадлежность и права доступа к каталогу:

   ```
   у.м.$ sudo chown -R root:root /root/.ssh
   у.м.$ sudo chmod -R go= /root/.ssh
   ```

---

теперь вы сможете монтировать каталоги: на вашей локальной машине процесс *sshfs* будет выполняться от вашего имени, а на удалённой процесс *sshd* будет выполняться от имени *root-а*:

```
$ sshfs root@удалённая-машина:/ ~/локальный/каталог
```

что позволит вам редактировать файлы в этом каталоге (например, `~/локальный/каталог/etc/sysctl.conf`), не натыкаясь на ошибки типа:

> The document could not be saved

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, надо добавить опцию `-oallow_other`, чтобы не только рут мог редактировать файлы, бонусом добавить сжатие - ключ `-C`

Ну и неочевидный вопрос- username на удаленном компьютере вообще имеет права на редактирование тех файлов? 
`ls -l` может помочь :)

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/path/to/user.key username@1.2.3.4:/ ~/mounted.fs -oallow_other -C
```

Comment: Про неочевидный вопрос: захожу тем же пользователем через ssh и через `sudo vim filename` правлю. Вроде как есть права.

Comment: Про сжатие - это просто для экономии трафика?

Comment: сжатие - спорная опция, реальная скорость передачи может и упасть при использовании `-C`, так как упрётся в итак загруженный CPU, например

Comment: в случае с текстовыми файлами может дать приятное ускорение, с бинарниками или не заметно или несколько хуже.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому поможет. Столкнулся с такой темой. При смене ОС на сервере, откуда монтировал директорию, также столкнулся с проблемой монтирования. Если монтируете через `fstab`, то почистите старые записи на пользовательском ПК в `/root/.ssh/know_hosts`.